# ASP.NET MVC Export XML based on XML-Schema

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq, xsd

Based on a given XML-Schema, I want to create an XML-Document and offer it as download within an MVC 5 application. I am using EF and Linq to Entity in the application. I am not sure which approach to use for creating the XML-File. Any idea what would best fit my needs?:

- XMLWriter
- XMLDocument
- Linq to XML
- A typed DataSet

The exported XML-File (based on older files) will have around 500KB and I have around 2500 Users. Not all users will simultaneously download their XML-File but I also don’t know how many will do download the file at the same time. Should I create the file in memory (by using a MemoryStream or a typed DataSet) or should I write it first on disk (FileStream and XMLWriter/XMLDocument) and then offer it for download?

**Update**
- A different xml file will be generated for each user
- The application will be hosted on-premise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use XmlSerializer.

First define class as Serializable

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

Then use XmlSerializer:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClasse));
var xmlString = serializer.Serializer(new MyClass);
```

If you are working with cloud, save this Xml File in S3 for AWS or Blobs for Azure.

If you are working with a single server, create a cache for this file in memory, you can use the [OutputCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute to create a cache very easy. Something like that:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 360/*seconds*/)]
public ActionResult CreateXml()
{
    //code here
}
```

Using [OutputCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) you have 3 ways to define what makes the request different from another, they are:

- **VaryByCustom** => Any text that represents custom output-caching requirements.
- **VaryByHeader** => A semicolon-separated list of HTTP headers that are used to vary the output cache.
- **VaryByParam** => A semicolon-separated list of strings that correspond to query-string values for the GET method, or to parameter values for the POST method.

Example of XmlDataSet vs XmlSerializer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5dzcP4

Comment: Hi Alberto! So you suggest I create a POCO class that I fill with the needed data and then serialize this class to XML. Is this approach not somehow similar with a typed DataSet? As I mentioned, I already have the XSD-File so I could easily create a typed DataSet and then use the WriteXML() method to create the File. What will be the advantage when using the XmlSerializer?
The application will be self-hosted (on premise) so I could use the OutputCache attribute, but because I have to generate for each user a different xml file, I am not sure if the cache will really help me in this scenario.

Comment: I changed my question with some improvements. I prefer XmlSerializer because its easier to work than dataset, less lines of code, also is faster too and more flexible, but if you fell more comfortable with dataset, go ahead and use it. About Output cache for each user, I added in question 3 ways that you can use to make request different.